# Prove that if the function $f$ be continuous and strictly increasing is dense.

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continuity

Let $g:[a,b] \rightarrow\mathbb R$ be continuous and strictly increasing. Show that $\{p \circ g : p \text{ is a polynomial}\}$ is dense in $C[a,b]$.

Comment: $g$ is a homeomorphism and $\{p\in C([0,1]): p \text{ is a polynomial}\}$ is dense in $C([0,1])$.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an outline:

Since $g$ is strictly monotone, it has a continuous inverse. Let $[c,d] = g([a,b])$ and
select $f \in C[a,b]$.

Consider approximating 
$f \circ g^{-1}$ with a polynomial $p$ and how you use this to answer the question.

Comment: Can't we use Stone-Weierstrass theorem?

Comment: Yes, that is implicit above. Use the Weierstrass approximation theorem to find a polynomial $p$ that approximates $f \circ g^{-1}$.